# Get latLng by clicking on a kml marker's infoWindow, for DirectionsService()

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, marker, infowindow

I have a simple JS script to display markers on a google map by reading a kml file with a list of placemarkers, and show the current location of the user.
Clicking on a marker shows the name and description of each placemark in an `infoWindow`, by default.

My question is how to add an option to run a `directionsService.route(directionsRequest, ...)` any selected marker is the destination, and the current position the starting point (double clicking on the marker or have a link added in the `infoWindow` seems the most intuitive way, but maybe someone has a better idea)...

Here is the current basic JS script (works fine now, API called with https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=IDXXX but it removes the possibility of only look at the markers' information, as clicking on markers immediately triggers the route rendering) :

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    var center_map = new google.maps.LatLng(45,-4);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: zoomvalue,    // defined on the page
        center: center_map,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        scaleControl: true
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: urlkmlfile,    // defini sur page qui appelle ce script
        preserveViewport: false
    });
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);

    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
            if(typeof pos_infowindow == "undefined") {
                pos_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    disableAutoPan: true,
                    map: map,
                    position: pos,
                    content: 'Votre position'
                });
            }
            else {
                pos_infowindow.setPosition(pos);
            }
    // add code here
        },
        function() {
            // alert('no geolocation');

        },
        { timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: true }
        );
    }
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Then get the latLng by clicking on any kml marker, to display the route to follow, but I'd like another option than 'click', to keep the possibility to look at infowindows data without triggering a route (if I put 'dblClick' in the `addListener` event below, it still only zooms in) :

```
if (pos) google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    var name_marker = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
    var text_marker = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
    var pos_marker = kmlEvent.latLng;
    var offset_marker = kmlEvent.pixelOffset;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var directionsRequest = {
    origin: pos,
    destination: pos_marker,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    };
    // alert('start ' + pos + ' destination ' + pos_marker);
    directionsService.route( directionsRequest, function(response, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)
        {
            new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                map: map,
                directions: response
            });
        }
        else{
  // alert ('problem');
        }
    }); 
});
```

Is there an easy way to do this ? I'd want to keep the 'click' event for reading each marker's data, and 'dblClick' event, or a link added in the `infoWindow`, to trigger the `directionsRequest` I'd like to keep it simple.

Comment: The posted code contains syntax errors (`pos_infowindow` is not a constructor).  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I was wondering why no geolocation anymore ! After some corrections, I get status "REQUEST_DENIED", so `DirectionsRenderer` is not applied. (Also I understand Firefox doesn't accept `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` without SSL/https).

Comment: Those sound like completely different questions, to which there are already answers.

Comment: Not a different question, I wanted to render this route (which doesn't fire anyway) by double clicking on a marker, or by clicking on a link in the infowindow. I just posted this code as an example of what I'm trying to do. If it's too complicated, no problem !

Comment: can you add the kml data - or a link to it if this is live?

Comment: kml file is large, but I just successfully validated it on different websites... the code `alert('start ' + pos + ' destination ' + pos_marker);` shows that latitude and longitude are correct for both origin and destination, just before the `directionsRequest`... Do I need to activate something on Google API console to use ? I have no special account with them, and can not create a new one (I can enter a project name, but the button to create it is not activated, although it says I have 11 projects left in my quota....).

Comment: Update : now the script in my original post works... status 'OK' after I finally managed to register in the Google API console (I tried 3 times and had to wait for minutes to log in), activate Directions API, add a ´key=ID´ in the call to maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js (no key mentioned in the examples I followed, though)... So back to my initial question :  how could I render this route by **double clicking** on a marker (overriding the zoom in function of the dblclick in google maps ?), or by **clicking on a link added in the infoWindow** of the markers ?

Comment: I see the request was made in 2011 already to implement dblclick and rightclick on kmlLayer objects... https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820673 Apparently they can't do it, so I suppose there is no way to capture a click on the infoWindow either... Thanks for the thumb down, anyway.

Comment: You can capture a click on HTML content in the Infowindow (that doesn't have anything to do with the API once it is rendered)

Answer (score 1):

[KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/kml#KmlLayer) doesn't support the double click event (the only mouse event it supports is click).

One option would be to add a "get directions" link to the rendered HTML in the infowindow, then use the `event.latLng` of that click event for the destination:

```
ctaLayer.addListener("click", function(event) {
  infowindow.setContent(event.featureData.infoWindowHtml+"<br><a href='javascript:getDirections("+event.latLng.toUrlValue(6)+");'>get directions</a>");
  infowindow.setOptions({pixelOffset: event.pixelOffset});
  infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
  infowindow.open(map);
});

function getDirections(lat, lng) {
  start = pos_infowindow.getPosition(); // current position as defined in the geolocation function
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  destination = latLng; // position of the marker clicked, as defined by the kml file
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsRequest = {
    origin: start,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
  };
  directionsService.route(directionsRequest, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else
      alert('Directions Request failed: ' + status);
  });
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/88tk3pdq/11/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var pos_infowindow;
var infowindow;
var directionsDisplay;

function initialize() {
  var center_map = new google.maps.LatLng(45, -4);
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5, // defined on the page
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    scaleControl: true
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    map: map
  });
  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: "http://www.geocodezip.com/state_capitals.xml", // defini sur page qui appelle ce script
    preserveViewport: false,
    suppressInfoWindows: true
  });
  ctaLayer.setMap(map);
  ctaLayer.addListener("click", function(event) {
    infowindow.setContent(event.featureData.infoWindowHtml + "<br><a href='javascript:getDirections(" + event.latLng.toUrlValue(6) + ");'>get directions</a>");
    infowindow.setOptions({
      pixelOffset: event.pixelOffset
    });
    infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
    infowindow.open(map);
  });

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        if (typeof pos_infowindow == "undefined") {
          pos_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            disableAutoPan: true,
            map: map,
            position: pos,
            content: 'Votre position'
          });
        } else {
          pos_infowindow.setPosition(pos);
        }
        // add code here
      },
      function() {
        alert('no geolocation');
        pos_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          disableAutoPan: true,
          map: map,
          position: {
            lat: 39.011902,
            lng: -98.4842465
          }, // default to Kansas
          content: 'Votre position'
        });
      }, {
        timeout: 15000,
        enableHighAccuracy: true
      }
    );
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function getDirections(lat, lng) {
  start = pos_infowindow.getPosition(); // current position as defined in the geolocation function
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  destination = latLng; // position of the marker clicked, as defined by the kml file
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  var directionsRequest = {
    origin: start,
    destination: destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
  };
  directionsService.route(directionsRequest, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else
      alert('Directions Request failed: ' + status);
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id='map-canvas'></div>
```